# Xamarin android build issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

getting below error on my xamarin Android application. Please help me to resolve this issue.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(5,5):
>   Error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to
>   metadata item
>   'Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat/BuilderExtender' (defined
>   in 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved.

Comment: What version of Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.Android are you using? You can try and disable the linking step in your android project as a workaround...

Answer (score 1):

First, update Xamarin Studio and Xamarin Android to latest version. Then, clean your solution and set target to Android 4.4. Set also the linking option to None.

After all these steps, rebuild your solution and run, it should work. Please try it.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the problem by setting the linking option to None.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat than first of you have to get latest version of xamarin studio and also android sdk then you will build successfully please try it.

Answer (score 0):

May you don't have the package for AppCompat. Download latest Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat libraries from NuGet and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to add AppCompat library to your app.

Be sure that you download the SDK [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Znr.png). When you download these packages don't choose the last stable version. Instead choose any older version [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnMYm.png).